# How to modify table and procedures without losing data if it has in it ?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem. I deployed a database with website at customer computer. Now he has entered a lot of data in TABLE1. I have done some modifications to the Table1 i.e. changing datatype as well as 2 procedures. Now I want to add this at client side but all data will be lost. How can I add this without losing the data at his side and applying my changes ?

I am usign sql server 2008 R2.

Comment: Make a backup table, fill it with current data, adjust TABLE1 and then fill it with backup data?

Comment: how about generating only script without data

Comment: Depending on the changes you may be able to modify the table using ALTER statements. Can you show the table design before/after?

Comment: That can work, but that means after you generate script, alter columns, insert data in it, you'll have to drop ORIGINAL table so you can rename new table, basically ether way you go, make sure to have a backup and you won't lose data. Simple as that

Comment: Use [ALTER TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement to change the structure of your table. This won't delete anything so no data will be lost (at least if you are not dropping columns of course).

Comment: Veljko is right, if you just use Alter Table or any script you can image, it will cause something, Make a backup table, insert all your data in it,drop the original one and rename the backup

Comment: If for example your client has populated a `varchar` field with a mixture of numbers and letters and you subsequently change the datatype to a numeric datatype then you need to manually fix the data. Same goes if they are saving dates into a varchar and you change to a datetime - you need to manually fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to backup you current table first... then you can now use that backup table to restore again after doing what you want to do.. see below steps...

Backup your table, below is the syntax to duplicate your exact table.

```
SELECT * INTO BackUpTable1 FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

i) Knowing the exact change is important.Like you change the datatype to what.what was earlier.What type of data is already there.
Suppose all data in server are int in varchar column then changing it to int won't loose any data.

ii) Import server table data to local,and do the changes there.See what happen.

iii) May be you hv to create script for it to avoid it.

iv) Taking back up of server table is utmost important.